# What is the most efficient way to organize and query large amounts of sensor data in GridDB?

Tags: griddb

I am currently working on a project that involves storing and querying large amounts of sensor data. I have chosen to use GridDB as the database for my project due to its support for high-throughput data ingestion and real-time querying capabilities. However, I am facing some challenges when it comes to organizing and managing the data within the GridDB cluster.

I have different types of sensor data, each with its own unique set of attributes and properties. For example, I have temperature sensor data that includes the temperature value and a timestamp, while I have humidity sensor data that includes the humidity value and a timestamp. I have been using a separate container for each type of sensor data, but this approach is becoming increasingly difficult to manage as the amount of data grows.

I am wondering if there are better ways to organize and manage my sensor data within the GridDB cluster. For example, is it possible to store multiple types of sensor data in a single container and still be able to perform efficient queries on the data? Can I use GridDB's built-in indexing and sharding capabilities to improve the performance of my queries? Are there any best practices or guidelines for structuring and querying large amounts of sensor data in GridDB?

Overall, I am looking for suggestions or advice on how to optimize my use of GridDB for my sensor data project, as it's becoming increasingly difficult to handle the data that I am collecting and querying with my current approach.

Comment: indexing is a good start, and in case the the interval and time where humidity and temp are collected is the same you could store them in the same container: | id | temp | hum | timestamp |. But if your are querying (selecting) them seperately, that approach results in a bigger load in terms of data returned by the query. _"this approach is becoming increasingly difficult to manage as the amount of data grows"_ Can you elaborate a bit?